# Remove app from IntentChooser in android

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I have an android app which can open specific urls. So in my Manifest I add intent-filter section like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data andriod:host="someurl.com"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
```

When user clicks on my links(outside of the app) my app is shown as one of the apps that can open url and it's fine.

But I have links inside my app that can started with "someurl.com" and in this situation I should remove my app from IntentChooser dialog. I do this like below:

```
public Intent generateCustomChooserIntent(Intent prototype) throws Exception {
    List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<Intent>();
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(prototype, 0);

    if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            // do not include my app in intent chooser dialog
            if (resolveInfo.activityInfo == null || resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName.equals(getPackageName())) {
                continue;
            }

            // add Intent to intent chooser dialog
            Intent targetedShareIntent = (Intent) prototype.clone();
            targetedShareIntent.setPackage(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName);
            targetedShareIntent.setClassName(resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName, resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
            targetedShareIntents.add(targetedShareIntent);
        }

        if (!targetedShareIntents.isEmpty()) {
            // pass new Intent to create no chooser in first row
            Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(targetedShareIntents.get(0), getString(R.string.open_link_with));
            targetedShareIntents.remove(0);

            // pass extra intent chooser
            chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[targetedShareIntents.size()]));
            return chooserIntent;
        }
    }

    // there is no appropriate intent to run
    throw new Exception();
}
```

And it's fine too.

But in some android devices(like samsung A5 2016) when I ask for intents which can handle url, **it just return my app as appropriate app(and doesn't include apps like google chrome)**, then I remove my app from IntentChooser dialog, and then nothing left to choose from.

How can I solve this?

Comment: tried different `flags` for `queryIntentActivities`? what does your debug session say about `resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName`?

Comment: When I catch this line: List<ResolveInfo> resInfo = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(prototype, 0); most devices returns all intents which can handle url, but in some devices it's just my app and nothing else. What do you means by different flags? Any special flag do you mean?

Comment: are you sure `Intent prototype` is formed properly? maybe `"all other devices"` report wrong list of intents?

Comment: Here's my prototype intent: Intent prototype = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW); prototype.setData(Uri.parse("someurl.com"));

Comment: I'va already used this method to create final intent list

Comment: ok so if you pass `Intent prototype` to `Intent.createChooser` (with no `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`) how many activities do you see?

Comment: There is no activity inside intent. I just call startActivity for chooserIntent. resInfo in some devices contains all activities which can handle url and in some devices it's just my activity.

Comment: but what do you see if you pass `Intent prototype` to `Intent.createChooser` (with no `EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS`) ?

Comment: If I don't pass EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS android doesn't show any chooser dialog and automatically handle url with given intent(in this situation my app).

Comment: ok so try adding those two categories: DEFAULT and BROWSABLE to your prototype Intent - `Intent#addCategory(String category)`

Comment: I tried. It didn't worked :(

Comment: so try MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY flag

Comment: It didn't worked too.

Answer (score 3):

There is workaround [here](https://movieos.org/2015/working-around-android-m-intent-resolving/) which you can use like this

```
public Intent generateCustomChooserIntent(Context context, String url) throws Exception {
        Uri fakeUri = Uri.parse("https://www.google.com");
        Uri realUri = Uri.parse(url);
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fakeUri);
        List<ResolveInfo> resInfo;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                    shareIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_ALL);
        } else {
            resInfo = context.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(
                    shareIntent, 0);
        }

        if (!resInfo.isEmpty()) {
            List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = removeCurrentApp(context, realUri, resInfo);

            if (!targetedShareIntents.isEmpty()) {
                // pass new Intent to create no chooser in first row
                Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(
                    targetedShareIntents.get(0), context.getString(R.string.open_link_with));
                targetedShareIntents.remove(0);

                // pass extra intent chooser
                chooserIntent.putExtra(
                        Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS,
                        targetedShareIntents.toArray(new Parcelable[targetedShareIntents.size()]));
                return chooserIntent;
            }
        }

        // there is no appropriate intent to run
        throw new Exception();
    }

    @NonNull
    private List<Intent> removeCurrentApp(Context context, Uri realUri, List<ResolveInfo> resInfo) {
        List<Intent> targetedShareIntents = new ArrayList<>();
        String currentPackageName = context.getPackageName();
        for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfo) {
            // do not include my app in intent chooser dialog
            if (resolveInfo.activityInfo == null) {
                continue;
            }
            String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (currentPackageName.equalsIgnoreCase(packageName)) {
                continue;
            }

            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, realUri);

            intent.setClassName(
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName,
                    resolveInfo.activityInfo.name);
            intent.setPackage(packageName);
            targetedShareIntents.add(intent);
        }
        return targetedShareIntents;
    }
```